# System command executes but is immediately backgrounded

Tags: ssh, pascal, lazarus, freepascal, delphi

I'm attempting to use the TProcess unit to execute ssh to connect to one of my servers and provide me with the shell. It's a rewrite of one I had in Ruby as the execution time for Ruby is very slow. When I run my Process.Execute function, I am presented with the shell but it is immediately backgrounded. Running `pgrep ssh` reveals that it is running but I have no access to it whatsoever, using `fg` does not bring it back. The code is as follows for this segment:

```
  if HasOption('c', 'connect') then begin
    TempFile:= GetRecord(GetOptionValue('c', 'connect'));
    AProcess:= TProcess.Create(nil);
    AProcess.Executable:= '/usr/bin/ssh';
    AProcess.Parameters.Add('-p');
    AProcess.Parameters.Add(TempFile.Port);
    AProcess.Parameters.Add('-ntt');
    AProcess.Parameters.Add(TempFile.Username + '@' + TempFile.Address);
    AProcess.Options:= [];
    AProcess.ShowWindow:= swoShow;
    AProcess.InheritHandles:= False;
    AProcess.Execute;
    AProcess.Free;
    Terminate;
    Exit;
  end;
```

`TempFile` is a variable of type `TProfile`, which is a record containing information about the server. The cataloging system and retrieval works fine, but pulling up the shell does not.

Comment: do you still need an answer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
...
AProcess.ShowWindow:= swoShow;
AProcess.InheritHandles:= False;
AProcess.Execute;
AProcess.Free;
...
```

You're starting the process but not waiting for it to exit. This is from [the documentation on `Execute`](http://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/fcl/process/tprocess.execute.html):

> Execute actually executes the program as specified in CommandLine, applying as much as of the specified options as supported on the current platform.
>
> If the poWaitOnExit option is specified in Options, then the call will only return when the program has finished executing (or if an error occured). **If this option is not given, the call returns immediatly**[sic], but the WaitOnExit call can be used to wait for it to close, or the Running call can be used to check whether it is still running.

You should set the `poWaitOnExit` option in options before calling `Execute`, so that Execute will block until the process exits. Or else call `AProcess.WaitOnExit` to explicitly wait for the process to exit.

Comment: Setting either of those causes my input to be hidden and all subsequent lines of output on the remote to add three tab characters at the beginning of the line. I'm having an extremely hard time figuring out why, any ideas?

Comment: If you have a new question, you should ask a new question. And include all of your relevant source code in its current form.

Comment: The correct option is poUsePipes to allow the process to communcate with the parent via the streams that tprocess provides. you must set the pipe buffer accordingly via pipebuffersize. you should use execute not waitforexit. you are running assynchronous, not synchronously. essentially this answer is wrong and i will write mine later.