# Input hidden, output has excess indentation

Tags: ssh, pascal, lazarus, freepascal, delphi

As formerly stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32366090/system-command-executes-but-is-immediately-backgrounded), I am trying to recreate an SSH profile manager in Pascal that I had originally written in Ruby. With the answer provided I have been able to get the shell to stay open and accept input. Now I have the new problem of any and all input is hidden and all output seems to be tiling with several tab characters before each line. The updated relevant code is as follows:

```
if HasOption('c', 'connect') then begin
  TempFile:= GetRecord(GetOptionValue('c', 'connect'));
  AProcess:= TProcess.Create(nil);
  AProcess.Executable:= '/usr/bin/ssh';
  AProcess.Parameters.Add('-p');
  AProcess.Parameters.Add(TempFile.Port);
  AProcess.Parameters.Add('-tt');
  AProcess.Parameters.Add(TempFile.Username + '@' + TempFile.Address);
  AProcess.Options:= [];
  AProcess.ShowWindow:= swoShow;
  AProcess.InheritHandles:= False;
  AProcess.Execute;
  AProcess.WaitOnExit;
  AProcess.Free;
  Terminate;
  Exit;
end;
```

The output provide looks like this:

[image: terminal output]

I ran `ls`, `pwd`, and `exit` in that order.

Comment: It's not about tabs. The lines are each missing a carriage return at the end. They only have line feed. So each new line starts in the column right after the one left off by the previous line. The code you listed doesn't seem to show how/where you output this information, so it's hard to tell more detail than that.

Comment: It's an SSH connection, so the output is not made by my code, it's generated by the remote server.

Comment: I am on Linux. The terminal emulator I'm using is called Yakuake, and all other terminal emulators have the same issue. I'm not processing or even generating the output whatsoever. My code opens up an SSH connection to the server in whatever terminal ran it, and then presents me with the console. Sort of an Execve type thing, except it doesn't replace the current process so I can do more tasks after the shell exits.

Comment: It's still a LF versus CRLF issue from the looks of it. Not sure what your terminal emulator settings are.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So probably you use crt or some other terminal library that puts the terminal into raw mode, requiring both a cr and lf.

Remove crt from the uses clause, and probably it will go better

Comment: That...worked perfectly. I can't believe it was that easy. Thank you so much!